# Is there a fix for scroll position change bug with Google Maps InfoWindows?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I implemented Google Maps on a site using the standard built-in InfoWindows functionality (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows). When an InfoWindow is closed by clicking on the "X" in the top right corner, the window.scrollY is changed by the height of the InfoWindow, as long as you aren't at the very top (window.scrollY == 0). Here's a jsfiddle I found while Googling the issue which, when modified a bit, shows the issue well.

```
$(function () {
    demoMap = {
        initMap: function () {
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(41.097905, -73.405006);
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 16,
                center: myLatlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }
            this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

            this.addMarker();
        },

        addMarker: function () {
            var self = this;
            var contentString = "<div id='content'>";
            contentString += "<div id='title'>Mr. Frosty's Deli and Grill</div>";
            contentString += "<div id='info'><p>10 1st Street</p><p>Norwalk, CT 06855</p><p>(203) 956-5767</p><p><a href='http://thebeachburger.com/'>thebeachburger.com‎</a></p></div></div>";

            var latlng = this.map.getCenter();

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latlng,
                map: this.map,
                title: "Mr. Frosty's Deli and Grill"
            });

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: contentString,
                disableAutoPan: true               
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function () {
                infowindow.setOptions({pixelOffset : self.getInfowindowOffset(self.map, marker)});
                infowindow.open(self.map, marker);
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function () {                
                infowindow.close();
            });
        },

        getInfowindowOffset: function (map, marker) {
            var center = this.getPixelFromLatLng(map.getCenter()),
                point = this.getPixelFromLatLng(marker.getPosition()),
                quadrant = "",
                offset;
            quadrant += (point.y > center.y) ? "b" : "t";
            quadrant += (point.x < center.x) ? "l" : "r";            
            if (quadrant == "tr") {
                offset = new google.maps.Size(-70, 185);
            } else if (quadrant == "tl") {
                offset = new google.maps.Size(70, 185);
            } else if (quadrant == "br") {
                offset = new google.maps.Size(-70, 20);
            } else if (quadrant == "bl") {
                offset = new google.maps.Size(70, 20);
            }

            return offset;
        },

        getPixelFromLatLng: function (latLng) {
            var projection = this.map.getProjection();          
            var point = projection.fromLatLngToPoint(latLng);
            return point;
        }
    }

    demoMap.initMap();
})();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/svigna/SJCNp/

If you add some height to the body (for example 2000px) and scroll a bit away from the top of the page, then click an InfoWindow closed, it will jump down the page by the exact height of the InfoWindow. I assume it has something to do with the fact that Google removes the elements entirely from the DOM when you close them, rather than simply using CSS classes to show/unshow the windows.

I scoured the internet for an answer, but it seems no one has noticed it, or no one cares, since it's kind of a small issue. The only solution I could think of is countering the scrollY change with a window.scrollTo in the opposite direction by the height of the InfoWindow (I couldn't get the actual InfoWindow element node to measure it's current offsetHeight, so I had to force all InfoWindows to have a specific height to set that same height in my JS).

Comment: You can also just simply add `overflow-anchor:none;` to the div element of your map as per the workaround that's pointed out here: https://issuetracker.google.com/163214518#comment3

Comment: That's a good one, but it's not supported by IE. https://caniuse.com/#search=overflow-anchor

Comment: Yes, you have a point. But the issue is not existing/reproducible in IE (or at least in version 11, where I have tested this).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling Google maps infowindow.open causes website to scroll down to the infowindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67895102/calling-google-maps-infowindow-open-causes-website-to-scroll-down-to-the-infowin)

Comment: Hi @leonheess, it's been a while since I posted this issue, but the link you provided seems to be a different issue to this one. This issue has to do with the InfoWindow closing, and not when it opens. I guess Google Maps has a lot of undesirable behavior. ;)

Comment: Hi @GregGaede, you're right. Someday I'll hopefully learn to read past the title. I retracted my close vote - have an upvote instead.

Comment: Ok, thanks, you get one too! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bug has been driving me nuts, I'm glad I'm not alone :)

It's not super elegant, but I noticed it wasn't happening when I triggered `infowindow.close()` manually, only when I actually clicked the default close button. So in the end, I hid the close button, added my own with `infowindow.setContent()`, and used that to close the infowindow.

Comment: Hey rosie, nice to see an answer in here. :) Your method is definitely better than my way of solving it. So I might end up marking it as the right answer if I can get it to work.

How do you select the custom info window element from Javascript to use `infowindow.close()`? the InfoWindow object in Google Maps doesn't expose the node itself as far as I know, and since the elements aren't actually in the DOM until you open them, you can't exactly select them. Did you use a direct onclick attribute on the custom element?

Comment: Ok, nevermind. I got it to work with a small setTimeout that waits for Google to create the window. It's not exactly clean, but it works. ;)