# Calling Google maps infowindow.open causes website to scroll down to the infowindow

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

**I am pretty sure this was not the default behaviour for Google Maps API for quite some time, but it must have changed in the meantime.**

I modified Fiddle provided by google: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows

added `1000px` "content" div on on top:

```
<div style="height: 1000px">CONTENT</div>
```

and added "auto" opening of infowindow to the script

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'tilesloaded', function () {
  infowindow.open(map, marker);
});
```

**JS Fiddle:**

https://jsfiddle.net/ym3c2e8u/

**Problem:**

If you comment out opening infowindow line, notice that the page will load and show you the top "CONTENT". 
If the infowindow is being opened, the browser will automatically scroll down to centre on this element.

This is really frustrating and I would like to prevent this behaviour.

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/190075886

Comment: Oh well, I expected that but my google search did not result in that issue from google tracker. BTW, thanks for the downvotes, as if I did not put any effort to describe the problem or it is a duplicate, but I don't see how this question does not follow SO guideline.

Comment: The necessary code to reproduce the problem should be included **in the question itself**. If your fiddle gets deleted tomorrow, your question will be mostly useless. Btw. there is nothing definitive in a close/down-vote. You could for instance create a working stack snippet that demonstrates the issue, link your question to the issue in the tracker and vice-versa. That would be useful for everyone.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, I'm updating documentation now!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default behavior of `InfoWindow.open()` is to have the browser focus on the element. This can be changed by using [InfoWindowOpenOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/info-window#InfoWindowOpenOptions).

```
infowindow.open({anchor: marker, shouldFocus: false});
```

instead of:

```
infowindow.open(map, marker);
```